# RIP Dennis “Denny” O’Neil

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam, comics

[Dennis O'Neil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_O%27Neil), an American comic book writer and editor, principally for Marvel Comics and DC Comics from the 1960s through the 1990s, and Group Editor for the Batman family of titles until his retirement, passed away on Tursday. Time to reread *[The Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_(comics))*.

[image: Tweet by DC Comics]